# Remove pricelist button odoo16

Tags: button, odoo, odoo-16

I cannot find where to remove the pricelist button on my website. In Odoo 15 there was an option to remove it, but in odoo 16, I've only figured out to remove it by taking it out of the html/css code. Is there any other way?

I thought it could be something we could fix with a plug-in or with another theme but I would prefer to find a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the given navigation in order to remove the price list from the website: website > eCommerce > Price lists.

Once you have reached the "Price lists" section, you can de-select the price list. Please refer to the attached screenshots for further guidance. Please let me know if you need any further assistance.

[image]